# Was Bishop II actually a human?

Tags: alien-franchise, alien-3-1992

At the very end of Alien<sup>3</sup>, we meet a character (credited as Bishop II) who claims to be

> the creator of the Bishop android.

He goes on to claim

> that *he* is indeed human.

What confuses me is that he

> is bleeding something that looks like blood after being hit on the head, but his ear seems to be pointing out at a very weird angle, that doesn't look like it was a type of injury a real person could have.

Here are some pictures to illustrate what I'm talking about:

> [image: Bishop II front]
>  [image: Bishop II side]

### Edit:

According to the [wiki page for Michael Bishop on `alienfilmspedia`](http://alienfilmspedia.wikia.com/wiki/Michael_Bishop) the question whether he's actually human or not is currently open.

Comment: I've had cats come home like that...Real cats. :)

Comment: @MajorStackings: Human cats?

Comment: Only the first two movies are canon. Well, those, and possibly the Gibson script.

Answer (score 11):

Bishop II (Michael Bishop) is actually a human-being, the designer of Bishop the android.

How do we know this? Well Bishop II doesn't bleed like an android (bleeds red blood), he responds to pain as opposed to Ash and Bishop the android. He shows emotion when Ripley decides to end her life along with the alien Queen. The movie script and novelisation say so.

Early script:

[image]

Later version:

[image]

Due to Bishop's nature (he was manipulative), the ear could be a some form of plastic or other kind of surgery, a fake ear - an implant.

Comment: I was thinking that the *red* blood could have been an update over the *milky* blood in android technology. However, how does a fake ear fit into the picture, that I don't get.

Comment: The ear was just a speculation, since he designed the android, he could have designed himself a missing hand or ear. He could have lost it somehow and replaced it with a fake one.

Comment: Like bitmask, I always took the fact that Bishop II was hardly even fazed from the hit to indicate that he was indeed a more advanced model of android, but a droid all the same. The Company was extremely manipulative, and while Bishop from Aliens may have had programming in him to obey and protect humans, it wouldn't be a stretch for there to be models that simulate humans more effectively for cases that require a more personal touch (including being able to lie and manipulate people). As an extra piece of evidence he is called Bishop II in the script, as though denoting a model number.

Answer (score -2):

He's probably a second bishop, advanced, with new red blood to give an authentic human-like appearance. Androids can be programmed to lie, like the other person said before, the company that Ripley discussed the crash of the Nostromo with could all be androids themselves. The ones who were all sitting at the table before she hung with hikes and his marine friends, even the lady that was smoking at the table that was questioning Ripley, and even van Buren himself could all be made to look authentic like Ash in the first movie. What about the colonist on LB426?

Comment: That's tremendously unintelligible.